# Laravel search query with oneToMany foreign table value

Tags: laravel

I have 2 tables

```
Entry

 - id
 - title
 - submitter_name
 - client_name
 - agency_id

Agency
  - id
  - name
```

Entry Model

```
public function agency(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Agency');
}
```

and Agency Model

```
public function entries(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Entry', 'entry');
}
```

I need to find all Entrys from database based on title,submitter_name,client_name,agency_name

The first 3 are easy

```
public function searchByData(Request $request) {

    $Entrys = Entry::where('title', 'LIKE', '%'.$request->title.'%')
    ->where('submitter_name', 'LIKE', '%'.$request->submitter_name.'%')
    ->where('client_name', 'LIKE', '%'.$request->client_name.'%')
    ->get();

    return view('entries.index')->with($Entrys);
```

But I'm failing miserably in finding Entries based on agency name.

Comment: Use `whereHas()`: https://laravel.com/docs/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
public function searchByData(Request $request) {

    $Entrys = Entry::where('title', 'LIKE', '%'.$request->title.'%')
        ->where('submitter_name', 'LIKE', '%'.$request->submitter_name.'%')
        ->where('client_name', 'LIKE', '%'.$request->client_name.'%')
        ->whereHas('agency, function($query) use($request){
             $query->where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->agency_name . '%');
        })
        ->get();

    return view('entries.index')->with($Entrys);
```

Comment: Tried it both ways, getting Unknown column 'agency.name' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `entry` where `title` LIKE %% and `submitter_name` LIKE %% and `client_name` LIKE %% and `agency`.`name` LIKE %optimist%)

Comment: so it's whereHas ..., Edited my answer